# Why this common greeting: Tzom kal?

Tags: hashkafah-philosophy, fast-days, language, tisha-bav

Tzom kal (easy fast) is a common greeting before the 9th of Av, but why?  It runs counter to the adage, "No pain, no gain". The no pain adage seems similar to L'fum tzaara agra – according to the effort is the reward (Pirkei Avos 5:22). Is no pain consistent with "a meaningful fast" (another common greeting)?  In short, why do we say Tzom kal?

Comment: How is this different from the common practice to not wish newborn babyies "have a painful life"?

Comment: @DoubleAA  We are undertaking a fast to afflict ourselves.  Why wish someone a light affliction?

Comment: because no one wants heavy affliction?

Comment: @DoubleAA  Is there a minimum amount of affliction, less than which is not true affliction?

Comment: Obviously, that depends how you define "true affliction"...

Answer (score 3):

We find something similar in Tefilas Zaka, said by many on Kol Nidrei night

> וְתֵן בָּנוּ כֹּחַ לְהִתְעַנּוֹת בְּיוֹם הַקָּדוֹשׁ הַזֶּה וּלְהַשְׁלִים הַתַּעֲנִית בְּכָל חֲמֵשֶׁת עִנּוּיִם, וְשֶׁלֹּא יִגְרְמוּ מַעֲשֵׂינוּ לִהְיוֹת נִכְשָׁלִים חַס וְשָׁלוֹם בְּשׁוּם אֶחָד מִן הַחֲמִשָּׁה עִנּוּיִים כִּי כֻלָּנוּ זֶרַע אַבְרָהָם יִצְחָק וְיַעֲקֹב יְדִידֶךָ.

> Give us strength to fast on this holy day, and may we complete the fast observing all the five deprivations; and may our misdeeds not cause us to fail in any one of them, for we are all the children of Avraham, Yitzchak, and Yaakov, whom You loved.

An easy fast can simply mean to have strength to finish it without having to break the fast for lack of strength (medical emergency)

Comment: I see your point, but perhaps a greeting that refers to having the strength to complete the fast would be more appropriate.

Comment: Perhaps, but what would one say "have a strong fast", "be strong"?

Comment: "Be strong" has a nice ring to it.  Any other ideas?